# Declare a constexpr static member that is a function of a potentially-absent member in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I have a templated class for which I would like to provide a constexpr integer whose value is determined by the presence or absence of a constexpr integer in the template parameter:

```cpp
template<typename Traits>
class Foo
{
  static constexpr int MaxDegree =
    std::conditional<
      std::is_integral<Traits::MaxDegree>::value,
      std::integral_constant<int, Traits::MaxDegree>,
      std::integral_constant<int, 0>
    >::value;
};

struct TraitA { };
struct TraitB { constexpr static int MaxDegree = 1; };

int main()
{
  std::cout
    << Foo<TraitA>::MaxDegree /* should be 0 */ << " "
    << Foo<TraitB>::MaxDegree; /* should be TraitB::MaxDegree == 1 */
    << "\n";
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work since `std::is_integral` fails for TraitA. Is there anything that will work?

I'm constrained to c++11.

Comment: This is not the main reason that it doesn't work, but you are using `std::conditional` wrong. It only has a `::type` member, not a `::value` member. And it is pointless to use it if you only want to produce a value instead of a type. You could simply use the ternary operator (`... ? Traits::MaxDegree : 0`) instead. (Only that this won't work here either if the member `::MaxDegree` may not exist.)

Comment: @user17732522 The whole point is that `Traits::MaxDegree` member may not exist, so the ternary operator will not work. I understand `std::conditional` may not be the solution, but don't know how else to ask the question... I can't find a way to avoid ambiguity when `Traits::MaxDegree` exists while providing a default value when it doesn't. Maybe I should ask if there is a template in `<type_traits>` that will return false (instead of just failing to compile) when `decltype(...)` does not exist?

Comment: Sorry, I intended to come back and write an answer, but got distracted. Now you already have an answer that should (almost) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Traits::MaxDegree
```

yields a compiler error, if the member doesn't exist. This means you cannot use this code as part of the expression directly.

You could use constexpr functions with SFINAE to implement this though:

```
template<class T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<decltype(T::MaxDegree)>::value, int>::type GetMaxDegree()
{
    return T::MaxDegree;
}

template<class T>
constexpr int GetMaxDegree(...) // this one is only used, if the first version results in a substitution failure 
{
    return 0;
}


template<typename Traits>
class Foo
{
public:
    static constexpr int MaxDegree = GetMaxDegree<Traits>();
};
```

Comment: When I try this, I get a compile error that the function is ambiguous in the case where `Traits::MaxDegree` exists. I haven't been able to figure out how to force your first implementation of GetMaxDegree() to be preferred.

Comment: @Drone2537 You could e.g. let the first overload take an `int` parameter (`constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<decltype(T::MaxDegree)>::value, int>::type GetMaxDegree(int)`) and then call it with `0` as argument (`GetMaxDegree<Traits>(0);`). It looks to me that this was the intent.

Comment: Thanks! That does work for my case, so I'm marking this as answered. I am still curious if there's a cleaner way to do this.